# EF CodeFirst y .net MVC Error en insert con Id como Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de login en MVC, que incluye las siguientes entidades: Sujeto,Usuario y Roles
El modelo de cada entidad es el siguiente:

```
public partial class syssujetos
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SujetoId { get; set; }                

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string cifdni { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string nombre { get; set; }
RECORTO LAS COLUMNAS QUE SON MUCHAS


public partial class sysusuarios
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }            

    [StringLength(150)]
    public string username { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Pass { get; set; }

    public bool? usuarioactivado { get; set; }

    public string comentarios { get; set; }

    public syssujetos Sujeto { get; set; }

}

public partial class sysroles
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int RolId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string nombre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string descripcion { get; set; }

    public bool? desistema { get; set; }

    public bool? deacceso { get; set; }
    public ICollection<syssujetos> Sujetos { get; set; }
    public sysroles()
    {
        Sujetos = new HashSet<syssujetos>();
    }
}
```

Aquí el Controlador

```
var idrol = Request.Form["idrol"];
        //objUser.Sujetos.id
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // && a.Pass.Equals(objUser.Pass)
            using (testModel db = new testModel())
            {
                //var usuario = db.Set<sysusuarios>();    
                syssujetos sujeto = new syssujetos();
                sysroles rol = db.sysroles.Where(r=>r.nombre=="USUARIO").FirstOrDefault();
                objUser.Sujeto.Roles.Add(rol);

                rol = db.sysroles.Where(r => r.RolId.ToString() == idrol).FirstOrDefault();
                objUser.Sujeto.Roles.Add(rol);

                db.syssujetos.Add(objUser.Sujeto);
                db.sysusuarios.Add(objUser);

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Home", "Index");
            }
        }
        return View(objUser);
```

Estoy recogiendo los datos correctamente en el controlador y asignando aparentemente bien también los valores de las entidades siendo **ManytoMany** entre sujeto y roles y **OneTomany** entre sujeto y usuarios. Pero al hacer SaveChanges en el modelo me da un error de SujetoId es Null, a pesar de que revisando el valor de la entidad, que además es Identity como véis, dicho valor corresponde con 0 y no se ve Nulo. No entiendo porque determina que es null.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cargando nuevamente la entidad, te recomiendo hacerlo con Entity-Framework ya que por codefirst si hay algun cambio en la BBDD tienes que modificar el codigo por completo.